# Ideal way to instantiate abilities in a class give a dynamic list of abilities to use?

Tags: game-design, architecture, objects

I have a PlayerClass class that is used to set my Player's class. For instance, this will make him a warrior:

```
 PlayerClass warrior = new WarriorClass();
```

WarriorClass will instantiate abilities like so:

```
 Ability ability1 = new LeapAbility();
```

Now my problem is that I will eventually dynamically update my Warrior's abilities (think talent trees or perks).

So say I give warrior a list of abilities to use. How do I do this in code? Right now I need to know the Abilities before hand and hard code their instantiation in.

Put another way, how do I instantiate a dynamic list of objects? I'm open to other solutions too if this doesn't make sense or is impossible.

Comment: You want to **decorate** your warrior with a **list** of abilities. So **PlayerClass.AddAbility(new LeapAbility()) I guess.

Comment: OK, I didn't think of feeding in an object like that. What would the other end look like? Something like this? Ability ability1 = new abilityParameter()? I'm not sure how to set it up so that the code knows to chose LeapAbility in the first place though. Only option i see is a list of all the skills in a big case or if statement.

Comment: What language you target? And you could look for design patterns like composition, decorator, abstract factory (producing players and abilities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a function that takes in a string, which can be loaded dynamically, and returns a new ability.

```
Ability createAbilityById(String s) {
    switch (s) {
        case “leap”: return new LeapAbility();
        case “foo”: return new FooAbility();
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also look into reflection if your language supports it, but it may be overkill or too complicated.

Comment: Thanks. In concept this is where I was landing. Any idea if I've architected myself into a corner on this one? I'm not against this, it just feels big and clunky.

Comment: Well, I don't know your game, or how it's structured, but here's what I think. This is obviously clunky, and error prone, but should be okay for a solo developer. You have to think about how you define these skill trees. Are you loading them from a JSON file or something, or defining them in code? If it's the former, you would probably need a massive switch statement anyways, because it's hard to write a nice way to turn {"abilityName": "leap"} into a useful object without one. If it's the latter, just keep the skill tree code next to the creation code so you remember to update it every time.

Comment: Yeah, just a solo dev working on a terraria mod. I was hoping to gain insight into how this would be done in a real game. JSON/Dictionary files came to mind but I'll get there if I need to.